# Magento 2 Contact form error

Tags: magento2, error, contact-us

I'm using Magento 2, and I'm getting the below error if I try to use the contact form. Does anyone have any idea what it might be?

> We can't process your request right now. Sorry, that's all we know.

Comment: You are using magento  in localhost ?
Then there is possibility of there is not SMTP configured an because of that mail not send and give error like that.

Comment: Hi @paresh , no I'm not in localhost , I'm using GoGeek shared hosting from siteground..

Answer (score 3):

You can see this message inside **Post controller** of contact module.

This message is display because your mail is not working. You have to configure your mail setting inside localhost for works it proper.

There is not SMTP configured on your localhost so mail is not sending and you have faced error like above.You can refer below links to configure  mail sending.

[Gmail setup in localhost](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94093/magento-2-how-to-configure-gmail-smtp-for-email-sending)

Or

[This module also works for gmail setup](https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp)

Comment: Hi @Rakesh , but the thing is that I'm not in local , I'm using GoGeek shared hosting from siteground..

Comment: Have you checked your other mail is working or not like account create, login mail, sales mail or not?

Comment: yes the other mail works , like if I register , I get the confirmation mail..

Comment: @alexcr did you resolve the problem? i am also using siteground and experiencing the same issue

Comment: @KrisWen I think I did, honestly I don't remember right now.. have you tried to contact siteground support? are you using any extension?

Comment: @alexcr Thanks, i contacted siteground and figured out. They had some spam feature switched on somehow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Might be because of the following bug in Magento: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6153

Would recommend that you try to set up an e-mail template for the Contact form to see if that resolves things.

Answer (score 0):

On the server I have postfix up and running and I have tested it with this php script

```
<?php
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $from = "mymail@gmail.com";
    $to = "target@gmail.com";
    $subject = "PHP Mail Test script";
    $message = "This is a test to check the PHP Mail functionality";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
    echo "Test email sent";
?>
```

I receive the message without problems but not from Magento.