# How to get processed email template using template id in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, template, email-templates

**I wanted to load a particular processed email template by using its id**. how to process this in magento 2.
in magento 1.x the code is like

```
 $sTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
->load($templateId)
->getProcessedTemplate(array(
    'firstname' => 'John',
    'lastname' => 'Doe'
));
```

Please help me.

Thanks.!

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132391/how-to-send-mail-programmaticlly-in-magento2 https://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-send-transactional-email-programmatically-in-your-custom-module/

Comment: Did you got answer?if so please post here

Answer (score 1):

To do the equivalent in Magento 2 you need to use the `\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder` class, as a very simplified example:

```
class Email
{
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    )
    {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_transportBuilder= $transportBuilder;
    }

    public function generateTemplate($templateId)
    {
        $emailTemplateVariables = [
            'firstname' => 'John',
            'lastname' => 'Doe',
        ];

        $template = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
            ->setTemplateOptions([
                'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
            ])->setTemplateVars($emailTemplateVariables);

        return $template;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$transportBuilder = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder');
$link = "Store Link";
$subject = "Link for Orders on";


$myfile = 'Attachment_file';
$vars = array( 'subject' => $subject,'link' => $link);
$filename = $myfile;

$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('12')
                    ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId(),])
                    ->setTemplateVars($vars)
                    ->setFrom(array('email' => 'noreply@abc.com','name' => 'general'))
                    ->addTo(array('To' => 'To@abc.net','To2' => 'To2@abc.net'))
                    ->addAttachment($filename, $filename);

$transport = $transport->getTransport();
$transport->sendMessage();
```

You need to check this from live.