# Does Magento2 send an email when order is cancelled by default?

Tags: magento2, attributes

I have custom functionality where orders can be canceled. I was wondering if M2 has some settings that sends automatic email to customer whose order was canceled? Or I need to implement it myself? If I need to implement it myself, I should follow this [How to send mail programmaticlly in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132391/how-to-send-mail-programmaticlly-in-magento2)? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess magento is not sending email default when order canceled while we can make a custom module for it.We will require a event and that will fire when order is canceled.

I have check magento2 event list and found event "order_cancel_after" that can we use in our observer.

You will need to create a module and use observer.

create `events.xml` file at path `companyname/modulename/etc/adminhtml/events.xml`

add the below code,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="order_cancel_after">
        <observer name="order_cancel" instance="companyname\modulename\Observer\ordercancel" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create observer file `ordercancel.php` at path `companyname\modulename\Observer` and insert the below code,

```
<?php

class ordercancel implements ObserverInterface
{

   public function __construct(
    ) {

    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       //implement here for sending mail
    }
}
```

There is also some discussion about that topic,you can review it

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10162

This will help you.