# Magento 2: Cancel order email sent to customer if admin cancel order

Tags: magento2, event-observer, cancel-orders

I am very beginner to magento and i am looking for answer,

if i cancel order from admin panel but cancel email order is not sent to customer.

If i want to sent email to customer what should i need to do?

I already create custom email template for cancel order

I am using Ranosys module to cancel order from frontend.

Answer (score 1):

[Reference Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/198952/72911)

> create **events.xml** file at path
> **Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="order_cancel_after">
        <observer name="order_cancel" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ordercancel" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Create observer file **ordercancel.php** at path
> `Vendor\Module\Observer` and insert the below code,

```
<?php

class ordercancel implements ObserverInterface
{
   public function __construct(
    ) {

    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       //implement here for sending mail
    }
}
```